# How to solve this error?

Tags: composer, magento-2.1.9, magento-upgrade, magento-2.1.10

I am trying to upgrade magento version from **2.1.9 to 2.1.10**

I got following error.

> Module 'Magento_Ui' from '/home/zitomer/upgrade.zitomer.com/app/code/Magento/Ui' has been
>   already defined in
>   '/home/zitomer/upgrade.zitomer.com/vendor/magento/module-ui

How to resolve this error as I am not able to upgrade on **2.1.10**

Comment: have you installed Magento 2 Github version?

Comment: yes.. i have installed git version

Comment: so you need to upgrade by git only

Answer (score 0):

If you installed M2 via composer you shouldn't have any files in app/code/Magento as the core modules reside in vendor/magento

Answer (score 0):

> /home/zitomer/upgrade.zitomer.com/app/code/Magento/Ui

navigate there and rename 
/home/zitomer/upgrade.zitomer.com/app/code/Magento/Ui/composer.json

-->**composer.off**

/home/zitomer/upgrade.zitomer.com/app/code/Magento/Ui/registration.php

**-->registration.off**

and try again

as @tecjam said you shouldn't have these files there.. :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete your core Magento 2 modules from `app/code/Magento` before deleting those you need run below commands

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/di/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ app/code/Magento/ vendor/magento

chmod 777 -R *

composer update && composer install

php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {}

find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {}

chmod u+x bin/magento

bin/magento maintenance:disable

bin/magento cache:clean
```

Now try again with composer upgate this time Magento will add all modules under `vendor/magento` folder.